# C++ count() function displays 1's and 0's rather than a total count when reading from a text file

Tags: c++, string, count

When counting a simple string, this works:

```
string x = "aabbcc";
int n = count (x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
cout << n;
```

This outputs '2' which is correct.
However, when I read in the string from a text file:

```
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(argv[1]);
string x;

if (myFile.is_open()) {
    while (myFile) {
        x = myFile.get();
        int n = count(x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
        cout << n;
```

This outputs 0's and 1's, the 1's appearing where the 'a's would appear.
Instead, I want a total count of a's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add the zeros and ones together in a `count` variable that you initiated to zero *before* entering the loop.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an assignment, not a question.

Comment: `myfile.get()` extracts a single character at a time.

Comment: *"This outputs 0's and 1's,"* -- more thorough debugging would include the value of `x` in the output. Demonstrate that `x` has the same value when read from the file as it had in your preliminary example.

Comment: `int n = std::count(std::istream_iterator<char>(myFile), std::istream_iterator<char>(), 'a');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() function is extracting a character at a time and passing it to variable X.

in every iteration of the while loop, X is of size 1.

Variable n contains the counts of 'a' character in the One character X has in it.

so, your output is instead *number of a's in every single character of the file.*
For the case when the character is actually 'a', You get to count that it found ONE count of a.

**use this:**
*easy option:*
change n to static

```
static int n = 0;
   while (myFile) {
        x = myFile.get();
        n += count(x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
   }
   cout<<n;
```

*hard option*
use a different get() function variation that gives you whole string. Pass that to string variable X

Comment: You forgot += I guess. Also, there is no reason to use count if you are reading one character each time.

Comment: thankyou, Adriel. OP is probably new to programming itself so I gave him an answer thats not optimum but closest to his original code. That way he'll understand the difference better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```cpp
ifstream myFile;
myFile.open(argv[1]);

if (myFile.is_open()) {
    stringstream iss;
    iss << f.rdbuf();
    string x = iss.str();
    int n = count(x.begin(), x.end(), 'a');
    cout << n;
}
```